# Use modal bootstrap as delete prompt in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I have a problem about to view or prompt a delete text confirmation, can I use the modal in bootstrap in prompt as a delete?

I try and it can delete  but in the first "id" only not in specific id and I don't know what to do to make specific id.

here is my view:

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
                    <?php if(sizeof($query) < 1) : ?>
                    No record in the database.
                    <?php else : ?>
                    
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>TITLE</th>
                                <th>CONTENT</th>
                                <th>LAST UPDATE</th>
                                <th>ACTIONS</th>
                               
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php foreach($query as $record) : ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $record->Id; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo word_limiter($record->Title, 5); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo word_limiter($record->Paragraph, 15); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $record->Lastupdate; ?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                                        <a href="<?php echo base_url('gallery/view').'/'.$record->Id; ?>" class="btn btn-info">View</a>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a>
                                        <a href=""  class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Delete</a>
                                    </div>    
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Delete</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Are you sure want to delete? </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <a  href="<?php echo base_url('Mywelcomepage/deletez').'/'.$record->Id; ?>" class="btn btn-default"  >Yes</a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code you do not need to add dynamic modal each time in your view :)

```html
    
        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <?php if(sizeof($query) < 1) : ?>
                            No record in the database.
                            <?php else : ?>
                            
                            <table class="table table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>ID</th>
                                        <th>TITLE</th>
                                        <th>CONTENT</th>
                                        <th>LAST UPDATE</th>
                                        <th>ACTIONS</th>
                                       
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <?php foreach($query as $record) : ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><?php echo $record->Id; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo word_limiter($record->Title, 5); ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo word_limiter($record->Paragraph, 15); ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $record->Lastupdate; ?></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                                                <a href="<?php echo base_url('gallery/view').'/'.$record->Id; ?>" class="btn btn-info">View</a>
                                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a>
                                                <a href=""  class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" onclick="confirm_modal('<?php echo site_url("controller/function/".$record->Id);?>','Title');" data-target="#myModal">Delete</a>
                                            </div>    
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            
                           
     <!-- (Normal Modal)-->
        <div class="modal fade" id="modal_delete_m_n"  data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content" style="margin-top:100px;">
                    
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align:center;">Are you sure to Delete this <span class="grt"></span> ?</h4>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="modal-footer" style="margin:0px; border-top:0px; text-align:center;">
         <span id="preloader-delete"></span>
                        </br>
                       <a class="btn btn-danger" id="delete_link_m_n" href="">Delete</a>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" id="delete_cancel_link">Cancel</button>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     <script> 
     function confirm_modal(delete_url,title)
     {
      jQuery('#modal_delete_m_n').modal('show', {backdrop: 'static',keyboard :false});
      jQuery("#modal_delete_m_n .grt").text(title);
      document.getElementById('delete_link_m_n').setAttribute("href" , delete_url );
      document.getElementById('delete_link_m_n').focus();
     }
     </script>
 <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Modal and custom JS function could be part of `else` check. :)

Comment: good to see snippet... just one suggestion, some improvement required in code formatting. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Try this coding ..

I have dynamically Generate the Model popup

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                    <?php if(sizeof($query) < 1) : ?>
                    No record in the database.
                    <?php else : ?>

                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>TITLE</th>
                                <th>CONTENT</th>
                                <th>LAST UPDATE</th>
                                <th>ACTIONS</th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php foreach($query as $record) : ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $record->Id; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo word_limiter($record->Title, 5); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo word_limiter($record->Paragraph, 15); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $record->Lastupdate; ?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                                        <a href="<?php echo base_url('gallery/view').'/'.$record->Id; ?>" class="btn btn-info">View</a>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a>
                                        <a href=""  class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?php echo $record->Id; ?>">Delete</a>
                                    </div>    
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <div id="myModal<?php echo $record->Id; ?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Delete</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Are you sure want to delete? </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <a  href="<?php echo base_url('Mywelcomepage/deletez').'/'.$record->Id; ?>" class="btn btn-default"  >Yes</a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
```